# How can I catch Exception raised in conftest.py

Tags: python, pytest

I've developed a Pytest plugin, which is used to make a http request to report the status of the tests to an external system during execution.

However, as I have no control over my colleagues' code, they might make some errors in `conftest.py`, which could crash before this plugin is even loaded. Therefore, the external system is unable to receive the test status and stuck there.

```py
@pytest.hookimpl(hookwrapper=True, trylast=True)
def pytest_sessionfinish(session, exitstatus):
    yield
    make_test_end_report_request(xxxxx)

@pytest.hookimpl(tryfirst=True)
def pytest_sessionstart(session):
   make_test_start_report_request(xxxxx)
```

In this situation, how can I ensure that I can catch all exceptions and send `error occured` report to the external system?

I also tries using `subprocess`

```py
popen = subprocess.Popen(
        ['pytest'] + params or [],
        stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
        stderr=subprocess.STDOUT,
        universal_newlines=True,
        shell=True
    )

return_code = popen.wait()
if return_code > 0:
    make_http_report(reason='Error occured')
```

but still can not 'try catch' which type of error is occured during the test.

Answer (score 0):

Elaborating on your attempt using `subprocess`, the exception could be caught as in the example below.

```
import subprocess

try:
    subprocess.run("pytest", shell=True, check=True, capture_output=True)
except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
    print(e.stderr.decode())
```

Setting the argument 'check' to True enables the 'CalledProcessError' exception to be raised in case the subprocess exits with a non-zero exit code. See the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.CalledProcessError) for more information.

So, if someone commits a mistake in `conftest.py`, and pytest raises an exception, you can catch it.

But bear in mind, like any other code, a pytest plugin should also be tested before commited. pytest has a plugin called `pytester` that tests pytest itself. It might be worth taking a look. See [Example](https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.1.x/how-to/writing_plugins.html#testing-plugins).